# Using Chef to configure Docker image?

Tags: docker, chef-infra, configuration-management

I am interested to see if I can use [Chef](https://www.chef.io) to configure a Docker container (sample [`Dockerfile` here](https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile)).

Say in my image, I wish to have an env var set, so my `Dockerfile` might contain an entry like so:

```
ENV MY_DB_URL http://devdb01.example.com
```

But in my QA/test environment, I might want it to look like:

```
ENV MY_DB_URL http://testdb01.example.com
```

In production, the value might be `http://db01.example.com`, etc. The point is that the values stored in my `Dockerfile` need to be different, depending on the environment (and possibly other conditions). This seems like a perfect job for a Chef template.

The problem is that the `Dockerfile` needs to be kept with my app's source code in VCS. So how can Chef be used to "inject" the `Dockerfile` with all the right values?

Comment: I assume you're looking for the `docker-container` resource from the docker cookbook [here](https://github.com/bflad/chef-docker) or on supermaket [here](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker#readme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually the genius of Docker- you can override most of the configuration setup in the container at launch time.  For example, our app depends on a variable APP_ENV to determine which environment it is running in (for things like database connection parameters and whatnot).  Running locally we run it with

`docker run -d -e APP_ENV=local ourCompany/ourApp`

while in staging it gets run with

`docker run -d -e APP_ENV=staging ourCompany/ourApp`

You can easily set this up using Docker-compose.

```
#base.yml
web:
  image: ourCompany/ourApp:latest

#staging.yml
web:
  extends: 
    file: base.yml
    service: web
  environment:
    - APP_ENV=staging
```

Then you can launch the base app with `docker-compose -f base.yml up -d`, or the staging version with `docker-compose -f staging.yml up -d`

Trust me- WAY less complicated than using Chef in your build system and building different versions of your image for different environments.

Comment: WAY less complicated (could be debated), but WAY more error prone after a few weeks with multiples envs (any templating system may be of help to create those files from a bunch of values instead of managing them manually)

Comment: I didn't notice this comment before... docker-compose allows a couple forms of inheritance, meaning that your 'staging.yml' file just has to specify the things that are different from your 'release.yml' file.

Answer (score 2):

If the code VCS is environment agnostic, then your release script needs to be responsible for updating the MY_DB_URL ENV command. Easiest way to do this is to stick a place holder in the VCS Dockerfile i.e. `ENV MY_DB_URL %MY_DB_URL%` and then replace it correct value for during the deployment.

Comment: Thanks @boyaa (+1) - so is there (generally-speaking) a use case for letting Chef configure your Docker images? I see there is [Chef management of containers](https://docs.docker.com/articles/chef/), but I don't think that's the same thing as what I'm talking about here. I *believe* that link is for when you want Chef to ensure that the Docker engine is installed on a VM (but please correct me if I'm wrong). Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The [chef-docker](https://github.com/bflad/chef-docker) cookbook might be of use to you. It provides resources so you can create containers via Chef. Here's an example from repo's README.

```
docker_container 'env' do
  repo 'debian'
  env ["PATH=#{node[:my][:path][:attribute]}", "FOO=#{node[:my][:foo][:attribute]}"]
  command 'env'
  action :run_if_missing
end
```

The code above sets environment variables in your container based on the node attributes you have set, which can be overridden in each environment.